# Combining use of Feynman trick, Reduction Formula, and Sequences for $\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2n}x\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$\sin^{2n}x$ can be written as $(1 - \cos^2x)^n$. Let

$$A_{a,n}=\int\limits_{0}^{\pi} (a - \cos^{2}(x))^{n}\,\mathrm dx$$

Which for when $a = 1$ gives the integral in question and

$$B_{a,n} = \int\limits_{0}^{\pi} (a - \sin^{2}(x))^{n}\,\mathrm dx$$

To use Feynman trick for $A_{n}$, setting $a = 0$ for the constant of integration gives $B_{0,n}$. Then differentiating under the integral with respect to $a$ gives

$$\frac {\partial f}{\partial a}=\int\limits_0^{\pi}(a-\cos^2x)^{n-1}\,\mathrm dx\qquad\implies\qquad\frac {\partial f}{\partial a}=A_{a,n-1}$$

You could get the same result when you switch $A_{a,n}$ and $B_{a,n}$. $A_{0,0}$ and $B_{0,0}$ would simply be both $\pi$.

With the above in mind, is there anyway to use Feynman trick, reduction formula, and sequences to solve

$$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2n}x\,\mathrm dx$$

If there is another way, please don't tell me, I want some more time to figure out this problem.  Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you want. Let
$$ I_n=\int_0^\pi\sin^{2n}(x)dx. $$
Then by integration by parts, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
I_{n+1}&=&-\int_0^\pi\sin^{2n+1}(x)d\cos (x)\\
&=&(2n+1)\int_0^\pi\cos^2(x)\sin^{2n}(x)dx\\
&=&(2n+1)\int_0^\pi\sin^{2n}(x)dx-(2n+1)\int_0^\pi\sin^{2n+2}(x)dx\\
&=&(2n+1)I_{n+1}-(2n+1)I_n 
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$ I_{n+1}=\frac{2n+1}{2n}I_n. $$
So
$$ I_n=\frac{2n-1}{2(n-1)}\cdot\frac{2n-3}{2(n-2)}\cdots\frac{3}{2}I_1=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n-2)!!}\frac{\pi}{2}. $$